# How to configure 2 seperate filters in spring boot webapplication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, filter, spring-boot

I'm trying to add 2 separate filters using FilterRegistrationBean in spring boot configuration.

Here is my implementation for 2 filters.

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {

    FilterResgistrationAccess registration = new FilterResgistrationAccess();
    registration.setFilter(new FeatureAccessFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/api/*");
    registration.setName("featureAccessFilter");
    registration.addInitParameter("paramName", "paramValue");
    registration.setOrder(1);
    return registration;
}

@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean shareFilterRegistration() {

    FilterResgistrationShare registration = new FilterResgistrationShare();
    registration.setFilter(new ShareAccessFilter());
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/content_external/*");
    registration.setName("shareAccessFilter");
    registration.setOrder(2);
    return registration;
}
```

But it's giving below error and failed to start application context. 
Please let me know how can I achieve the same.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'featureAccessFilter': 
Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: 
private org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean com.beroe.insync2.config.FeatureAccessFilter.filterRegistrationBean; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean] is defined: 
expected single matching bean but found 2: someFilterRegistration,shareFilterRegistration
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
```

Comment: It seems like spring is failing while creating instance of FeatureAccessFilter. Please post the code for same. As suggested by @guchuan, use qualifiers to defined and inject beans of same type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bean is searched by the type, and for both Bean the type is same so that's what the problem is.

To solve this, you can add @Qualifier to solve the autowire by bean name.

Or you can add @Primary to one of the Bean if one of them should be used by default.

For example,

```
@Bean
@Primary
FilterRegistrationBean someFilterRegistration() {
  ...
}
@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean shareFilterRegistration() {
 ...
}
```

for this, if you do

```
@Autowired
FilterRegistrationBean bean;
```

you get someFilterRegistration() autowired, and by doing

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("shareFilterRegistration")
FilterRegistrationBean bean;
```

you'll get the other one.

Comment: adding "@Primary" worked for me. I tried with "@Qualifier" before..it didnt work.
thanks for your help